# Wie unterscheidet man am besten zwischen dem inklusiven und dem exklusiven Wir?

Tags: word-usage

> Person A spricht mit B.
>
> Inklusiv:
>   A meint mit »wir« sich und B.
>
> Exklusiv:
>   A meint mit »wir« sich und C.

Selbst mit dem Wort »beide« ist es oft nicht eindeutig. Meint »Wir beide sind schön«, dass A sich und B oder sich und C schön findet?

Was könnte A sagen, um am einfachsten unmissverständlich das inklusive und das exklusive Wir deutlich machen?

Comment: Indem man statt "wir" eben "B und A" oder "C und A" sagt.

Comment: Wenn es um eine Kontrastierung geht (wir sind sparsam, die anderen geizig...), dann ist der einfachste Weg, ausdrücklich "wir" und "ihr" zu verwenden. Das Vorkommen von "ihr" beweist dann, dass das "wir" exklusiv war. Im umgekehrten Fall empfiehlt sich als kürzeste Lösung "wir alle".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die germanischen Sprachen, darunter Deutsch, kennen keinen Unterschied zwischen inklusivem und exklusivem Wir. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inklusives_und_exklusives_Wir#Verbreitung) wird diese Unterscheidung aber in rund 40% aller Sprachen der Welt gemacht, am häufigsten in Sprachen, die von Menschen gesprochen werden, die rund um den Pazifik leben.

Wie immer, wenn man in einer Sprache ein Feature braucht, das es dort nicht gibt, das man aber vielleicht aus anderen Sprachen kennt, muss man kreativ sein. Man muss das, was man sagen will eben in mehrere Worte packen. Im vorliegenden Fall muss man eben Aufzählungen verwenden.

Am einfachsten geht das beim dualen inklusiven Wir:

> Wir beide sind schön. = Du und ich sind schön.

Das Pronomen *du* macht hier eindeutig klar, dass der Adressat mitgemeint ist.

Auch das duale exklusive Wir macht wenig Probleme:

> Wir beide sind schön. = <*Name*> und ich sind schön. (z.B. Lisa und ich sind schön.)

Hier wird durch die Abwesenheit des Pronomens *du* klargestellt, dass der Adressat nicht im Subjekt enthalten ist.

Ähnlich kann man vorgehen, wenn mit *wir* mehr als zwei Personen gemeint sind:

inklusives Wir:

> Wir sind schön. = Du, <*Name*>, [<*Name*>, ...] und ich sind schön. (z.B. Du, Anna, Lisa und ich sind schön.)

exklusives Wir:

> Wir sind schön. = <*Name*>, [<*Name*>, ...] und ich sind schön. (z.B. Anna, Lisa und ich sind schön.)

Comment: Gibt es keine Möglichkeit, ohne Aufzählung auszukommen? Ansonsten könnte ich  ja gleich auf alle Pronomen verzichten.

Comment: Du kannst nicht auf alle Pronomen verzichten. Die erste Person Singular kann nur mit einem Pronomen gebildet werden (nämlich mit *ich, meiner, mir, mich*). Wenn du das durch deinen Namen ersetzt, musst du von dir selbst in der dritten Person sprechen, was deine Zuhörer verwirren wird. Ähnliche Probleme erwarten dich, wenn du *»du«* durch den Namen deines Gegenübers ersetzen willst. Aber davon abgesehen hält dich tatsächlich nichts davon ab, auf Personalpronomen zu verzichten. Aber ich sehe eigentlich keinen Grund, das zu tun.

Comment: Und genau die Verwirrung habe ich jetzt mit dem Wir, darauf wollte ich ja hinaus :)

Comment: Welche Verwirrung? Und warum erst jetzt? Dieses Feature hat es nicht nur im Deutschen nie gegeben, sondern es war in allen europäischen Sprachen nie vorhanden.

Comment: Aber wenn du Verwirrung suchst: Arzt zum Patienten: *»Na, was fehlt **uns** denn?«* In diesem Wir ist der Sprecher gar nicht inkludiert. Oder: Lehrer an der Tafel während er allein etwas vorträgt und die Schüler nur zusehen: *»**Wir** ziehen nun die Wurzel aus diesem Term, ...«* Dieses Wir schließt außer dem Sprecher niemanden ein. Oder wenn der Kaiser zum Volk spricht: *»Das Konzert hat **uns** sehr gefallen.«* Auch hier umschließt das Wir nur den Sprecher, sonst niemanden.

Comment: Die Verwirrung, wie ich am besten und unmissverständlich das Wir benutzen kann. Warum jetzt? Weil ich vorher mir dazu noch keine Gedanken gemacht habe. Ja, auch andere Sprachen haben das Problem, das macht es nicht besser. Danach führst du nur das Wirzen an, ähnlich dem Siezen, Duzen oder Manzen. Keine Ahnung warum, das hilft hir gar nicht. Stattdessen suche ich eine Wortkombination, die passt. Gäbe es WirX für exklusives Wir und WirI für inklusives Wir, dann wäre beispielsweise alles klar.

Answer (score 1):

Bei direkter Rede mit Sichtkontakt kann man gestisch entweder auf den Angesprochenen und sich selbst verweisen, bzw. für das exkludierende Wir in eine Richtung weisen, die als Cs Standort verstanden wird, sowie sich selbst.

Rein sprachlich kann man H. Schölnast folgen.

Üblich ist auch die Arbeit mit einem Komma:

> Susi und ich, wir sind die Kessler-Zwillinge.

Bzw.

> Du und ich, wir müssen raus in den Schnee!

Das *Wir* kann auch vor der Erläuterung stehen:

> Wir, meine Frau und ich, kaufen uns eine Harley.

Comment: Im Alltagsdeutsch kommt bisweilen auch noch das explizit reduzierte Wir vor: *Wir - also Du natürlich nicht - fahren morgen an den Bodensee.*